# Speeding up file comparisons (with `cmp`) on Cygwin?

Tags: bash, cygwin

I've written a bash script on Cygwin which is rather like `rsync`, although different enough that I believe I can't actually use `rsync` for what I need.  It iterates over about a thousand pairs of files in corresponding directories, comparing them with `cmp`.

Unfortunately, this seems to run abysmally slowly -- taking about ten (Edit: actually 25!) times as long as it takes to generate one of the sets of files using a Python program.

Am I right in thinking that this is surprisingly slow?  Are there any simple alternatives that would go faster?

(To elaborate a bit on my use-case: I am autogenerating a bunch of `.c` files in a temporary directory, and when I re-generate them, I'd like to copy *only* the ones that have changed into the actual source directory, leaving the unchanged ones untouched (with their old creation times) so that `make` will know that it doesn't need to recompile them.  Not all the generated files are `.c` files, though, so I need to do binary comparisons rather than text comparisons.)

Comment: For what it's worth, I've confirmed that `rsync` doesn't do what I want; it always resets the modified time on unchanged files, either to the timestamp on the original (if called with `-t`) or to the time of the transfer.

Comment: Interesting problem..I think it is also worth asking how to prevent sync from updating timestamp of a file it has not transferred

Comment: @MiserableVariable: Good thought -- that's now http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29845/how-can-i-do-a-copy-if-changed-operation.  (I don't think it's a duplicate; this is "how do I write this program better", while that is "can I avoid it entirely?".)

Comment: No, I don't think its a duplicate. I started out by writing "a better question would be" and changed it to "also worth asking" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should use Python to do some - or even all - of the comparison work too?

One improvement would be to only bother running `cmp` if the file sizes are the same; if they're different, clearly the file has changed.  Instead of running `cmp`, you could think about generating a hash for each file, using MD5 or SHA1 or SHA-256 or whatever takes your fancy (using Python modules or extensions, if that's the correct term).  If you don't think you'll be dealing with malicious intent, then MD5 is probably sufficient to identify differences.

Even in a shell script, you could run an external hashing command, and give it the names of all the files in one directory, then give it the names of all the files in the other directory.  Then you can read the two sets of hash values plus file names and decide which have changed.

Yes, it does sound like it is taking too long.  But the trouble includes having to launch 1000 copies of `cmp`, plus the other processing.  Both the Python and the shell script suggestions above have in common that they avoid running a program 1000 times; they try to minimize the number of programs executed.  This reduction in the number of processes executed will give you a pretty big bang for you buck, I expect.

---

If you can keep the hashes from 'the current set of files' around and simply generate new hashes for the new set of files, and then compare them, you will do well.  Clearly, if the file containing the 'old hashes' (current set of files) is missing, you'll have to regenerate it from the existing files.  This is slightly fleshing out information in the comments.

One other possibility: can you track changes in the data that you use to generate these files and use that to tell you which files will have changed (or, at least, limit the set of files that may have changed and that therefore need to be compared, as your comments indicate that most files are the same each time).

Comment: The benefit of the MD5 and other hashes version is that you can store the hash rather than perform a byte-by-byte comparison at the _next_ iteration. If you re-compute the MD5 each time for old files and new files both, it's not much different.

Comment: Agreed, that's clearly the problem.  Running `md5sum *` on the files in one of the directories is vastly faster, and (as @sarnold implies) the only "real" benefit that has is just that it's only starting one program; it's loading the same data.  Now to figure out whether there's an easy-enough way to get from there to what I need....

Comment: @sarnold: Right -- in the Python version, there's no point in computing MD5 hashes if they're not being stored.

Comment: @BrooksMoses: `md5sum -c` can do the verification for you, too. Hooray. :)

Comment: For the record: I discovered that Python has a `filecmp.cmp()` library function that is essentially equivalent to `cmp`, so I tried translating my script into Python.  It turned out to be possible to do that almost exactly word-for-word, and the execution time dropped from 197.2s to 10.4s -- comparable to the 8.1s required to generate the files in the first place, and far more tolerable!

Comment: @Brooks: Wow, that's a nice improvement. Thanks for the final details!

Answer (score 1):

If you can reasonably do the comparison of a thousand odd files within one process rather than spawning and executing a thousand additional programs, that would probably be ideal.

The short answer: Add `--silent` to your `cmp` call, if it isn't there already.

You might be able to speed up the Python version by doing some file size checks before checking the data.

First, a quick-and-hacky `bash(1)` technique that might be far easier if you can change to a single `build` directory: use the `bash` `-N` test:

```
$ echo foo > file
$ if [ -N file ] ; then echo newer than last read ; else echo older than last read ; fi
newer than last read
$ cat file
foo
$ if [ -N file ] ; then echo newer than last read ; else echo older than last read ; fi
older than last read
$ echo blort > file # regenerate the file here
$ if [ -N file ] ; then echo newer than last read ; else echo older than last read ; fi
newer than last read
$
```

Of course, if some subset of the files depend upon some other subset of the generated files, this approach won't work at all. (This might be reason enough to avoid this technique; it's up to you.)

Within your Python program, you could also check the file *sizes* using `os.stat()` to determine whether or not you should call your comparison routine; if the files are different sizes, you don't really care which bytes changed, so you can skip reading both files. (This would be difficult to do in `bash(1)` -- I know of no mechanism to get the file size in `bash(1)` without executing another program, which defeats the whole point of this check.)

The `cmp` program will do the size comparison internally IFF you are using the `--silent` flag *and* both files are regular files *and* both files are positioned at the same place. (This is set via the `--ignore-initial` flag.) If you're not using `--silent`, add it and see what the difference is.

Comment: For what it's worth, I am using `--silent`.  Also, I should note that this really needs to be optimized for the "nearly all files match" case -- most of the time when I call this, I've only actually changed a handful of the generated files.  Nonetheless, useful advice.